# Number of eigen values of an $N \times N$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the number of eigen values of a non-singular matrix and why ?

What would have happen if matrix is singular, lets say have 2 linear dependent rows.

Preparing for interview, stuck on this question, know the answer is because of characteristic polynomial, but do not have good way to put answer. Please help.

Comment: The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, which has degree $n$, the size of the square matrix. Depending on the matrix and the field of the coefficients, there can be from $0$ to $n$ eigenvalues. And all the cases occur. That the matrix is non-singular does not change that. The eigenvalues are nonzero, that's all. Also, sometimes one says that it has $n$ eigenvalues even if some of them are actually repeated.

Answer (score 1):

**No Conclusion**

- Possible eigenvalues of a non-singular real skew-symmetric matrix are purely imaginary. Consequently such matrices have no eigenvalue in $\mathbb R$ *i.e.* the number of eigenvalues is $0.$
- The roots of the characteristic polynomial of a $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices are all real whence the number of eigenvalues is $n.$
- You may form a $n\times n$ matrix which has exactly $i$ (*pre-assigned*) eigenvalues where $0\le i\le n$ as:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&2\\&&3\\&&&\ddots\\&&&&k\\&&&&&0&-1&-1&...&-1\\&&&&&1&0&-1&...&-1\\&&&&&1&1&0&...&-1\\&&&&&...&...&...&\ddots&...\\&&&&&1&1&1&...&0\end{pmatrix}$$

1. If $n-i$ is even take $k=i$ in $A;$
2. If $n$ is even & $i$ is odd, take $k=i-1$ in $A;$
3. If $n$ is odd & $i$ is even and *nonzero*, take $k=i-1$ in $A;$
4. For $i=0$ take any non-singular real skew symmetric matrix.

   All can be said about your second question is that $0$ is an eigenvalue here.

**Added:** The point made by [@A Walker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12084/a-walker) is relevant in this regards as polynomials factor linearly over any closed field.

Comment: It should be mentioned that the answer is in fact $n$ if we consider a matrix over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @AWalker: It's indeed relevant here. Thanks for pointing it out.